Android API 34: which version of Gradle?
As mentioned here,
I assume that to upgrade my react native project to API 34, I have to upgrade AGP minium to 8.1.1 so I use Gradle 8.1 and AGP 8.1.1
But after browser alot in stack overflow, I saw many people using Gradle 7.4
So which the minium Gradle or AGP should I use to for API 34?
Updated
As the accepted answer, I realized that I have really misunderstand the problem. My project work with API 34 and AGP 7.2.2, Gradle 7.4 now.

What you linked to is a table that describes the compatibility of versions of Android Studio with AGP versions. You can see that the minimum version of AGP for most recent Android Studio versions there is 3.2, so the API level is irrelevant.
This is not relevant to the question you are asking. If you want your RN application to target API level 34, you can do that regardless of AGP or Gradle versions.
You might have to change certain APIs you are using due to deprecations or changes that may have occurred from your current API level to 34.
If you want to use a newer version of AGP or Gradle, that will require you to upgrade your Android Studio version.

thank u. You helped me

@Yuqi - Glad I could help.
